# uncompressed file is bigger than original file in GZIP

Tags: c#, .net, compression, gzip

i'm using the following function to compress(thanks to http://www.dotnetperls.com/):

```
public static void CompressStringToFile(string fileName, string value)
    {
        // A.
        // Write string to temporary file.
        string temp = Path.GetTempFileName();
        File.WriteAllText(temp, value);

        // B.
        // Read file into byte array buffer.
        byte[] b;
        using (FileStream f = new FileStream(temp, FileMode.Open))
        {
            b = new byte[f.Length];
            f.Read(b, 0, (int)f.Length);
        }

        // C.
        // Use GZipStream to write compressed bytes to target file.
        using (FileStream f2 = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(f2, CompressionMode.Compress, false))
        {
            gz.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        }
    }
```

and for decompress:

```
static byte[] Decompress(byte[] gzip)
    {
        // Create a GZIP stream with decompression mode.
        // ... Then create a buffer and write into while reading from the GZIP stream.
        using (GZipStream stream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(gzip), CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            const int size = 4096;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int count = 0;
                do
                {
                    count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size);
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        memory.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
                }
                while (count > 0);
                return memory.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

so my goal is actually compress log files and than to decompress them in memory and compare the uncompressed file to the original file in order to check that the compression succeeded and i'm able to open the compressed file successfuly.
the problem is that the uncompressed file is most of the time bigger than the original file and my compare check is failing altough the compression probably succeeded.

any idea why ?

btw here how i compare the uncompressed file to the original file:

```
static bool FileEquals(byte[] file1, byte[] file2)
    {
        if (file1.Length == file2.Length)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < file1.Length; i++)
            {
                if (file1[i] != file2[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: How big are the strings?  You can't effectively compress short strings.  The compressor needs at least thousands of bytes to get enough statistics and matching strings in order to compress well.

Comment: i'm compressing files , log files and the biggest is 50 mb

Comment: What is the average length of the inputs to _each_ call of `CompressStringToFile`?

Comment: It is not exactly clear how you converted the original *string* that you compressed into the byte[] you passed to FileEquals().  Encoding accidents are common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method to compress a file:

```
public static byte[] Compress(byte[] raw)
{
using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(memory,
    CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
    gzip.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
    }
    return memory.ToArray();
   }
  }
}
```

And this to decompress :

```
 static byte[] Decompress(byte[] gzip)
{
// Create a GZIP stream with decompression mode.
// ... Then create a buffer and write into while reading from the GZIP stream.
using (GZipStream stream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(gzip), CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    const int size = 4096;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size);
        if (count > 0)
        {
        memory.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
    }
    while (count > 0);
    return memory.ToArray();
    }
}
}
```

}

Tell me if it worked.

Goodluck.

Comment: thanks i just tested it - and it works but current only in memory so i didn't use yet filestream, it should work as well no? what did i do wrong?

Comment: i think i understood my problem,  i did this before i called the compress function:
 private static void ZIP(string source_file)
        {

                string fileToZIP = File.ReadAllText(source_file);
                CompressStringToFile(source_file + ".gz", fileToZIP);    
        }    
so its becausse of the conversion to string  File.ReadAllText(source_file)

Comment: @MoshMosh yea i also think that the mistake in your code. im glad it worked for you now :)

Answer (score 1):

Think you'd be better off with the simplest API call, try [Stream.CopyTo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  I can't find the error in your code.  If I was working on it, I'd probably make sure everything is getting flushed properly.. can't recall if GZipStream is going to flush its output to FileStream when the using block closes.. but then you are also saying that the final file is larger, not smaller.

Anyhow, best policy in my experience.. don't rewrite gotcha prone code when you don't need to.  At least you tested it ;)